# Pegar endereço da imagem, jquery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Olá, bom dia!

Gostaria de obter o valor **SRC** da tag IMG, usando js/jquery.
No caso, seria https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPeE3.jpg

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>hello</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        function get(){
            //????
            //alert(img);
            alert('a');
        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="get()">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPeE3.jpg" width="100" height="100">
    </body>
</html>
```

é possível?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>hello</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        function get(){
            var linkImagem = $('#imagem').attr('src');
            alert(linkImagem);
        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="get()">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1gIalgU.jpg" width="100" height="100" id="imagem">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfeito! Nat, só mais uma coisa, teria como eu efetuar um replace nessa variável?

Comment: Algo desse tipo: var a = linkImagem.replace("i.imgur.com", "facebook");

Comment: Retorna sempre esse erro > Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: @Luanpedro Coloquei assim no jsFiddle e funcionou: var link2 = linkImagem.replace('i.imgur.com', 'facebook.com'); Vc está fazendo direto no console? Ou a página mesmo que está retornando isso? Veja: https://jsfiddle.net/ndelavi/s3u1fLdp/

Comment: https://pastebin.com/svvNbd6K

Comment: Estou colocando assim

Comment: Mudei algumas coisas no seu código: https://jsfiddle.net/ndelavi/s3u1fLdp/5/

Comment: Muito obrigado! <3

Comment: Por nada, só pra explicar, estava dando erro pq vc estava tentando executar o get() antes da página ser completamente carregada, então o jquery não estava conseguindo pegar o valor de linkImagem, trazendo sempre 'undefined'. Chamando o get depois do document.ready, forço a página ser carregada primeiro antes de chamar o get(). Que bom que ajudou. Até breve.